# Dynamically added instance method can not access class variable

Tags: ruby

(Question already posted at [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6877988), but did not evoke any answer there).

This is my code:

```
class MC
  def initialize
    @x = 5
    @@y = 6
  end

  def f
    puts @x
    puts @@y
  end
end

m = MC.new
m.f
```

`m.f` produces the expected output without an error:

```
5
6
```

But this:

```
def m.g
  puts @x
  puts @@y
end

m.g
```

produces:

```
5
warning: class variable access from toplevel
NameError: uninitialized class variable @@y in Object
```

Why can I access `@@y` from `f`, but not from `g`?

Mentioning of `toplevel` and `Object` in the warning and the error message is puzzling to me.

`@x` is printed as `5`, so its environment is `MC`. This excludes the possibility that `@x` and `@@y` in the definition of `m.g` refer to the toplevel environment (`Object`) instead of `MC`.

Why did I get the error message?

Comment: This was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24510948/477037

Comment: @Stefan: True. Unfortunately, there is no good explanation there as well.

Answer (score 5):

All variants below work:

```
def m.g; puts self.class.send(:class_eval, '@@y') end

def m.g; puts self.class.class_variable_get(:@@y) end

class << m; def g; puts self.class.send(:class_eval, '@@y') end end

class << m; puts class_variable_get(:@@y) end
```

But these fail:

```
def m.g; puts @@y; end

class << m; puts class_eval('@@y') end
```

I would consider this being a ruby parser glitch.

Comment: Note that the method `#class` "skips" the singleton class and returns `MC`. So the first 3 are not really surprising. You should also add the variants with `singleton_class` which show the same behavior.

Comment: Seems like the rules for constant lookup also apply to class variables, i.e. they are lexically scoped.

Comment: @undur_gongor `class << m` are the variants with `singleton_class`.

Answer (score 4):

You do not create `g` in the class `MC` but in `m`'s singleton class (a.k.a. eigenclass).

This is a class existing specifically for the object `m` to store the singleton methods that are defined just for `m`.

Comment: `class << m ; puts class_variable_get(:@@y) ; end` works perfectly. As well as `def m.g; puts self.class.class_variable_get(:@@y); end`. Which is a bit weird.

Comment: Note that this is only a part of the answer. The singleton class is a subclass of `MC` (`m.singleton_class.superclass # => MC`) and it thus "sees" `@@y` (`m.singleton_class.class_variables # => [:@yy]`). I'm missing why the lookup fails.

Comment: I guess it’s a parser glitch.